# find roots in noise (rand) fnc w fsolve (ValueError: The array returned by a function changed size between calls)

Tags: python-3.x

I do my first steps in python and find this blocking point. I tried to find a solutiuon by searching and testing alternativ variants. At the end I want find a y-value of a noise-added signal (i.e. y(x) = sin(x)+rand() where x(y) = 10). As a abstraction I'm locking for a zero-crossing.

But in general I have the problem that I didn't get the fsolve() working with a np.random.rand signal. It's working with the sin(x) but not with the (commented out) noise part. I try to form the array and check the dimension, kind and size.

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.style

matplotlib.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x = np.linspace(0,3,100)
print(len(x))
print(type(x))

rnd = np.random.rand(100)-0.5

def g(x):
    return np.sin(2*x)

def r(x):
    return rnd

print(g(x))
print(type(g(x)))

print(r(x))
print(type(rnd))


plt.plot(x, g(x), zorder=1)
plt.plot(x, r(x), zorder=1)

#well working
x_int = scipy.optimize.fsolve(g, 1.0)
y_int = g(x_int)

#not working -> ValueError: The array returned by a function changed size between calls
#x_int = scipy.optimize.fsolve(r, 1.0)
#y_int = r(x_int)

plt.scatter(x_int, y_int, marker='x', s=100, zorder=2, linewidth=1, color='black')

plt.xlim([0,3])
plt.ylim([-4,2])
plt.show()
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Oh, it looks that the problem is not only to heavy for beginners :-)